# discrepancy in CRX property data types in AEM

Tags: configuration, osgi, aem, sling, crx

While configuring mail service `com.day.cq.mailer.DefaultMailService`, I came to know that SMTP port should be an integer (`smtp.port=I"465"`).

But if I try configuring using `sling:OsgiConfig` node, as the CRX is not providing Integer for data type (only Decimal, Double and Long), I am not able to achieve this.

Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String` type in `sling:OsgiConfig` node to give the `smtp:port` in CRX/DE. This is internally processed by `DefaultMailService`.

If we see the `DefaultMailService` implementation `smtp.port` is `String`, is processed by annotations

```
@Property(intValue={25})
private static final String SMTP_PORT = "smtp.port";
```

Answer (score 0):

Sandeep is wrong, the internal representation is not `String`. The `SMTP_PORT` variable is of type `String`, because it holds a label and not the field value.
The actual value is of type `int`.
But you can set the value to Long in crx.de, because the value will be internally cast to `int` then.
`String` might also work, but I did not test that.